# Can I use a void* as a parameter to a function?

Tags: c++, oop, porting

I am porting some code over from C# into C++ and I am having trouble using the `void*` to take the place of a generic object. I am trying to pass the undefined pointer as a parameter for a function but have not had an success.

Here is the code to my class:

```
class ReceiveRequest
{
    typedef boost::function<void (std::string *message, ssError& e, void *payload) > receiveCallback;

    public:
    receiveCallback Callback;
    void* payload;

    ReceiveRequest(receiveCallback _Callback, void* _payload)
    {
        Callback = _Callback;
        payload = _payload;
    }

    void runCallback (std::string message, ssError e)
    {
        Callback(message, e, this->payload);
    }

    ~ReceiveRequest() {  }

};
```

And here are the errors I receive:

```
In file included from StringSocket.h:16,
                 from StringSocket.cpp:8:
ReceiveRequest.h: In member function ‘void ReceiveRequest::runCallback(std::string, ssError)’:
ReceiveRequest.h:30: error: no match for call to ‘(ReceiveRequest::receiveCallback) (std::string&, ssError&, void*&)’
/home/jsander/boost/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:761: note: candidates are: R boost::function3<R, T1, T2, T3>::operator()(T0, T1, T2) const [with R = void, T0 = std::string*, T1 = ssError&, T2 = void*]
```

Why does my `void*` variable become a `void*&` when I pass it as a parameter? To fix this should I just change the `typedef` function to take a `void*&` to fix my problem?

Comment: Why porting C# to C++ ?

Comment: For a school assignment

Comment: Thanks Jonathon for cleaning up my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the `void *`, it's the `std::string`. The callback is expecting a pointer but you're trying to pass a plain object.

...comments about why you should avoid using plain pointers in C++ aside.

Comment: @hededo You should accept this as the correct answer so Matti gets a cookie.